# How to create PDF file upload field for post like meta box field admin side?

Tags: plugins

I want the custom fields for PDF file upload on admin side for the post where i can select any PDF file for the any posts using custom code or any type of plugins.

can you recommend me please by which my problem can be solved ?

```
<?php

$array=array('posts_per_page'=>2, 'post_type'=>'post');
$mypost=get_posts($array);
//print_r($mypost);
foreach($mypost as $values)
{
    //print_r($mypost);




        echo "<p>" .$values->post_title."</p>";
        echo "<p>" .$values->post_content."</p>";
        echo "<p>" .get_the_post_thumbnail($values->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'thumbnail text-center' ))."</p>";
        echo '<p>' . date_i18n('d F Y', strtotime($values->post_date)) .'</p> ';
        //$ca = get_the_category($values->ID);
        //print_r($ca);
        //echo $ca[0]->name;
        $pdf_file =  get_field('pdf');
        print_r($pdf_file);

     if( $file ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$pdf_file.'">Download File</a>';
          }




}

 ?>
```

Comment: you can add a field in the backend with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: suppose i want to put upload fle URL in my href attribute of <a>anchor tag  to download button then how can i do it plz need your help?

Comment: in the creation of the field, did you use `pdf` for the field name ?

Comment: yes but i am not getting files on my template using this code plz tell what can do now or any other solution provide me if you have .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to create custom PDF upload field in custom post type:

1. Install [Advance Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) from wordpress.org
2. Go to **Custom Fields** and click on **Add New** button.
3. Follow instructions in below screenshot to add the custom field to upload PDF file.

[image]

4. Use below code to display content on post type template.

   ```
   $pdf_file = get_field('pdf_upload');

   if( $file ) {
       echo '<a href="'.$pdf_file.'">Download File</a>';
   }
   ```

Reference Documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: i am not getting an array after print_r($pdf_file);

Comment: For File field, as you see in the screenshot you can have any of three **Return values**: File Object, File URL and File ID. I have shown above to get direct URL of an uploaded file. You can refer reference URL for example of the other two options.

You will just get single URL value not an array...if you have implemented as per above example...

Comment: yes i am trying to get the url by using field name but it not returning any value as you instruct me...plz need your help

Comment: what is your field name?? is it same which I have given?? and where have you added code?? in archive template or single template or any other template?

Comment: field name is same which you given me and i am adding this code in other template.

Comment: I could help you more if you can provide me more information regarding template or share code here...The code I have given will only work if you are using it within post type loop or in the template when used within the limit of post object.

Comment: ok i added my code above in my question please see there once and check this code what i doing wrong.

Comment: any one can please suggest me other plugin to same task please.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code which I have corrected....there was just a minor issue with your code in If condition..

```
<?php

$array=array('posts_per_page'=>2, 'post_type'=>'post');
$mypost=get_posts($array);
//print_r($mypost);
foreach($mypost as $values)
{
    //print_r($mypost);




        echo "<p>" .$values->post_title."</p>";
        echo "<p>" .$values->post_content."</p>";
        echo "<p>" .get_the_post_thumbnail($values->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'thumbnail text-center' ))."</p>";
        echo '<p>' . date_i18n('d F Y', strtotime($values->post_date)) .'</p> ';
        //$ca = get_the_category($values->ID);
        //print_r($ca);
        //echo $ca[0]->name;
        $pdf_file =  get_field('pdf');
        print_r($pdf_file);

     if( $pdf_file ) {
         echo '<a href="'.$pdf_file.'">Download File</a>';
     }
}

 ?>
```